# How to express this action: Do not put the cake vertically to eat, put it horizontally?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

My toddler often puts the cake vertically to eat, as shown in the below picture

[image: Look at this picture]

It is hard for him to eat if he does like that, I want him to put the cake horizontally to eat like the below picture

[image]

How to express this action using common everyday terms: **Please Do not put the cake vertically to eat, put it horizontally?**

I also think about some adverbs such as "**upside down**", "**right side up**", etc.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a specific phrase for what you ask, but you might say “hold it flat when you eat it” or “hold it level when you eat it” or just “hold it up the right way”

Comment: @mclayton, so what is the opposite of "level"? Can I say "please do not hold it vertical" or "do not hold it uneven"?

Comment: Again, there’s no specific “right” expression, but maybe “don’t hold it on its side”? (And “uneven” wouldn’t really be the opposite of “flat” in this case)

Comment: @mclayton Would you support "hold it uprightly"?

Comment: @Ben A. - I’m not an expert in cake-holding, but I’d approve of the term ”hold it upright” :-)

Comment: _Vertical_ is rather a 'grown-up' word to use with a toddler. How about "Turn it sideways so that you can get it into your mouth" ?

Comment: @mclayton, does ”hold it upright” = ”hold it up straight”?

Comment: I've just checked that 'upright' is an adverb, too. So, see my suggestion reduced to 'upright' (previously: 'uprightly'). The shorter the better for toddlers.